# How to overwrite a non-Debian package?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

#### Background

I am trying to install [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive), so I am installing [Grive](https://github.com/Grive/grive). I previously tried to install [SyncDrive](http://www.noobslab.com/2013/09/syncdrive-google-drive-available-for.html), which isn't supported any longer. Now, I am having some conflicts between the two installations. (I am on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander).)

#### The problem

My installation of Grive was not working, indicating some missing dependencies. So I ran `sudo apt-get -f install`, but it gives me the following error:

```
Unpacking grive (from .../grive_0.3.0-1+git20131016~thefanclub~saucy1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/grive_0.3.0-1+git20131016~thefanclub~saucy1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/grive', which is also in package syncdrive 0.9-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

I tried to fix this using `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /usr/bin/grive`, but it is not a Debian package. So, how can I resolve this problem? Is there a way to force the overwrite of `/usr/bin/grive`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to uninstall `syncdrive` completely and then  try to correct broken dependencies,

```
sudo dpkg -P syncdrive
sudo apt-get install -f
```